# I don't know what is going on

Tags: modeling, faces

I followed a tutorial to make a sword in blender, but somehow managed to make this appear. Is this due to the fact that I have bevel and subdivise on (I did it in the right order)?
[Object mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiUhF.png)

[image: Edit mode]

Comment: If your object has some faces with flipped normals it can cause the bevel operation to invert

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don’t have multiple points overlapping. You may need to go into edit mode, select all and then merge by distance to remove vertices.